# C++ Run time efficiency

Tags: c++, runtime

I'm creating a hex board out of nodes.Everything I have in this bit of code works perfectly. My problem is the item that is starred slows down this loop from taking ~1 second to about 1 minute. It isn't the number of items in the vector because if i remove them all except the last one it still takes ~1 minute. either way there are no run time errors.

```
for (x = 0; x < size; ++x)
{
    for (y = 0; y < size; ++y)
    {
        this->nodes[x][y].neighbors = std::vector<node>(6);
        if ((x == 0) && (y == 0))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                nodes[x + 1][y],
                this->nodes[x][y + 1]
            };
        }
        else if ((x == 0) && (y == max))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x + 1][y],
                this->nodes[x][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x + 1][y - 1]
            };
        }
        else if ((x == max) && (y == 0))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x - 1][y],
                this->nodes[x][y + 1],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y + 1]
            };
        }
        else if ((x == max) && (y == max))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x - 1][y],
                this->nodes[x][y - 1]
            };
        }
        else if (y == 0 && (x != 0 && x != max))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x - 1][y],
                this->nodes[x + 1][y],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y + 1],
                this->nodes[x][y + 1]
            };
        }
        else if (y == max && (x != 0 && x != max))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x - 1][y],
                this->nodes[x + 1][y],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x][y - 1]
            };
        }
        else if (x == 0 && (y != 0 && y != max))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x][y + 1],
                this->nodes[x + 1][y],
                this->nodes[x + 1][y - 1]
            };
        }
        else if (x == max && (y != 0 && y != max))
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x][y + 1],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y]
            };
        }
        else
        {
            this->nodes[x][y].neighbors =
            {
                this->nodes[x + 1][y],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y],
                this->nodes[x][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x + 1][y - 1],
                this->nodes[x][y + 1],
                this->nodes[x - 1][y + 1]
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since that condition will be hit in all but 8 of the cases, it should be the one consuming the most time. but 1 second vs 1 minute makes no sense. how big is your board `size` again? and how big is `max` in relation to it? if they're not identical values I suspect you're walking on your automatic variable space by mistake.Since this is an initialization it would seem trivial to put together a stand-alone example that demonstrates the problem. Do so, and *debug this*.

Comment: size is 6 and max is 5. the vector is a 6 by 6 vector. max is the last index of the vector of size 6.

Comment: is `max == size`?  Why bother with `this->nodes[x][y].neighbors = vector<node>(6);`?  Why use `this->` everywhere? - so cluttered.  Have you turned your compiler's optimisation on (e.g. -O2 for most UNIX/Linux compilers, /O2 for Windows)?  What's the class definition and assignment operator for `node`?

Comment: Yeah, then I'm highly suspicious you're addressing out of range, but I'll wait for that [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to validate it.

Comment: @TonyD max = size-1. It is the maximum index of size. And "this" is because it's in a larger class.

Comment: @WhozCraig: well, `nodes[x+1][y]` et al always look beyond the elements initialised *in* this loop, so definitely there has to have been some previous initialisation for this to be valid.  dkimmel7: you could try changing all your `nodes[x][y]` to `nodes.at(x).at(y)` and see if it throws an exception indicating access outside the vector's content.

Comment: @dkimmel7: you don't normally need `this->` to access a data member; (incidentally, most people use a naming convention like `nodes_` or `m_nodes` for *documentation* value).

Comment: @TonyD I tried and no exception was thrown. I debug and it gets stuck for several minutes for no apparent reason and then evaluates correctly. But it's only that one element that is ever slow.

Comment: @dk I'm not sure why you keep bringing up that there were no runtime errors/exceptions. C++ vectors doesn't do any bounds checking if you use the `[]` indexing. (It does bounds checking if you use `vector::at()` IIRC.) It's very easy to write bad code that doesn't do the right thing and nevertheless not crash or throw exceptions or whatnot.

Comment: @SchighSchagh I changed them all to at() and there were no errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the idea is to track neighbours that you know have been pre-created, you probably only want to keep a reference or pointer to them; you should not ***copy the `node`s by value*** as you currently do.

You could use `vector<reference_wrapper<node>>` or `vector<node*>`, with respective initialisation like this:

```
nodes[x][y].neighbors = { ref(nodes[a][b]), ref(nodes[c][d])... };

nodes[x][y].neighbors = { &nodes[a][b], &nodes[c][d], ... };
```

With pointers, when you access `neighbors[n]` you'll obviously need to dereference the pointer too.

Regarding why it was so slow... the copying by value meant copying `node`s into `neighbours` was copying all those neighbouring `node`'s neighbours, and their neighbours, ad nauseum... getting slower and slower as the number of nodes with long neighbour hierarchies increased.

Comment: @dkimmel7 Can you edit the definition of `node` in to your question?  (You fixed your `XCoodinate` error?)

Comment: got it to work with the .get() method of the reference wrapper.

Comment: @dkimmel7: I see... can be necessary to do it explicitly if the `node` type can't be deduced from the context in which the `reference_wrapper` is used (when it can be deduced - which should be most of the time - the `operator node&()` kicks in).

Answer (score 0):

The slowness comes from 2 things:

- The last else clause gets hit the most.
- The last clause copies more node items than the rest

A few suggestions:

- Use pointers or indexes not `node` objects for neighbors. Less copying.
- It will be faster to have a fixed size array for neighbors. Will improve locality and memory significantly. You'll have to add a neighbor count for that array.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the speed except the last element of the else statement makes it 100x slower. Even removing all other elements that one takes forever to evaluate. Even though it generates no errors.